# Ignorar campos não preenchidos MySQL PHP

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Preciso trazer informações de uma table que utiliza vários campos. Essas informações precisam ser tratadas antes de entrar dentro de um Select do HTML. Toda estrutura para isso já está pronta usando AJAX mas estou com dificuldade em eliminar campos não preenchidos em determinadas colunas.

Minha estrutura da table está da seguinte forma:

```
id, id_fornecedor, propriedade, responsavel, endereco, telefone, email, variedade1, preco_variedade1, variedade2, preco_variedade2, variedade3, preco_variedade3, variedade4, preco_variedade4, variedade5, preco_variedade5, variedade6, preco_variedade6, variedade7, preco_variedade7, variedade8, preco_variedade8, variedade9, preco_variedade9, variedade10, preco_varidade10
```

O que eu preciso?

Exibir do meu select APENAS os resultados que tiveram as colunas preenchidas nas variedade. Impossível setar uma ou outra porque os registros são aleatórios. As que não foram preenchidas, preciso que o PHP ignore com o Select (MySQL) para que informações não preenchida deixem o Select (HTML) com espaços em branco.

O código atual do ajax é este primeiro e o de baixo é o PHP chamado pelo Ajax:

```js
$(function(){
  $('#propriedade').change(function(){
      if( $(this).val() ) {
          $('#variedade').hide();
          $('.carregando_variedades').show();
          $.getJSON('variedades.ajax.php?search=',{cod_propriedade: $(this).val(), ajax: 'true'}, function(j){
              var options = '<option value=""></option>'; 
              for (var i = 0; i < j.length; i++) {
                  options += '<option value="' + j[i].cod_variedade + '">' + j[i].variedade1 + '</option>';
                  options += '<option value="' + j[i].cod_variedade + '">' + j[i].variedade2 + '</option>';
                  options += '<option value="' + j[i].cod_variedade + '">' + j[i].variedade3 + '</option>';
                  options += '<option value="' + j[i].cod_variedade + '">' + j[i].variedade4 + '</option>';
                  options += '<option value="' + j[i].cod_variedade + '">' + j[i].variedade5 + '</option>';
                  options += '<option value="' + j[i].cod_variedade + '">' + j[i].variedade6 + '</option>';
                  options += '<option value="' + j[i].cod_variedade + '">' + j[i].variedade7 + '</option>';
                  options += '<option value="' + j[i].cod_variedade + '">' + j[i].variedade8 + '</option>';
                  options += '<option value="' + j[i].cod_variedade + '">' + j[i].variedade9 + '</option>';
                  options += '<option value="' + j[i].cod_variedade + '">' + j[i].variedade10 + '</option>';
              } 
              $('#variedade').html(options).show();
              $('.carregando_variedades').hide();
          });
      } else {
          $('#variedade').html('<option value="">– Escolha uma variedade –</option>');
      }
  });
});
```

```html
<?php
 header( 'Cache-Control: no-cache' );
 header( 'Content-type: application/xml; charset="utf-8"', true );

  include ('conn/conexao.php');
    
 $cod_propriedade = $_REQUEST['cod_propriedade'];

  $variedade = array();

  $consulta_variedades = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM cad_propriedades WHERE id = '$cod_propriedade'");
  $consulta_variedades->execute();

  $resultado_variedades = $consulta_variedades->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

  foreach($resultado_variedades as $row)
  {
    $variedade[] = array(

        'cod_variedade' => $row['id'],
        'variedade1'    => $row['variedade1'],
        'variedade2'    => $row['variedade2'],
        'variedade3'    => $row['variedade3'],
        'variedade4'    => $row['variedade4'],
        'variedade5'    => $row['variedade5'],
        'variedade6'    => $row['variedade6'],
        'variedade7'    => $row['variedade7'],
        'variedade8'    => $row['variedade8'],
        'variedade9'    => $row['variedade9'],
        'variedade10'   => $row['variedade10'],
  );
  }

  echo( json_encode($variedade) );

?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(function(){
  $('#propriedade').change(function(){
      if( $(this).val() ) {
          $('#variedade').hide();
          $('.carregando_variedades').show();
          $.getJSON('variedades.ajax.php?search=',{cod_propriedade: $(this).val(), ajax: 'true'}, function(j){
              var options = '<option value=""></option>';   
              for (var i = 0; i < j.length; i++) {
                  if (typeof(j[i].variedade1) != "")
                    options += '<option value="' + j[i].cod_variedade + '">' + j[i].variedade1 + '</option>';
                  if (typeof(j[i].variedade2) != "")
                    options += '<option value="' + j[i].cod_variedade + '">' + j[i].variedade2 + '</option>';
                  if (typeof(j[i].variedade3) != "")
                    options += '<option value="' + j[i].cod_variedade + '">' + j[i].variedade3 + '</option>';
                  if (typeof(j[i].variedade4) != "")
                    options += '<option value="' + j[i].cod_variedade + '">' + j[i].variedade4 + '</option>';
                  if (typeof(j[i].variedade5) != "")
                    options += '<option value="' + j[i].cod_variedade + '">' + j[i].variedade5 + '</option>';
                  if (typeof(j[i].variedade6) != "")
                    options += '<option value="' + j[i].cod_variedade + '">' + j[i].variedade6 + '</option>';
                  if (typeof(j[i].variedade7) != "")
                    options += '<option value="' + j[i].cod_variedade + '">' + j[i].variedade7 + '</option>';
                  if (typeof(j[i].variedade8) != "")
                    options += '<option value="' + j[i].cod_variedade + '">' + j[i].variedade8 + '</option>';
                  if (typeof(j[i].variedade9) != "")
                    options += '<option value="' + j[i].cod_variedade + '">' + j[i].variedade9 + '</option>';
                  if (typeof(j[i].variedade10) != ""l)
                    options += '<option value="' + j[i].cod_variedade + '">' + j[i].variedade10 + '</option>';
              } 
              $('#variedade').html(options).show();
              $('.carregando_variedades').hide();
          });
      } else {
          $('#variedade').html('<option value="">– Escolha uma variedade –</option>');
      }
  });
});
```

Comment: Olá amigo! Tentei o seu código aqui mas infelizmente não funcionou. Ele continua trazendo os campos em branco junto. Mesmo assim, obrigado pelo feedback.

Comment: Qual o resultado (json) que traz da requisição ajax?

Comment: Eu segui sua lógica e adicionei ao final de cada if o  && j[i].variedade1 != "" e ele funcionou. Se puder, faça uma nova resposta para que eu deixe ela aqui em destaque para quem visualizar a postagem de uma forma melhor.  MUITO obrigado pela ajuda Rodrigo. Grande abraço!

Comment: Isso que eu ia perguntar, porque se estivesse vazio era so alterar o código, mas deu certo então, vlw.

Comment: Alterei o código acima para ficar certinho.

Comment: Infelizmente não tenho reputação pra dar +1 na sua resposta mas com certeza vai ajudar muita gente. Abraço!

Comment: Sem problemas!!! Abraço!